# Find $f^{(k)}(0)$ of $f(x)=\arctan(x^n), n\in \Bbb N$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $n\in \Bbb N$, and $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$, $f(x)=\arctan(x^n)$. For any $k\in \Bbb N$, find $f^{(k)}(0)$.

Now, I found the first derivative:$$f'(x)= \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x^2}$$

I was thinking of maybe using Leibniz' rule but that doesn't seem like the best idea. What else can I do?

Comment: Multiply the both side by $(1 + x^2)$, then use Leibniz’s rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the geometric series formula gives
$$ f'(x) = \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x^{2n}} = nx^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-x^{2n})^j= \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^{j}nx^{2{jn}+n-1} = \sum_{\tilde \jmath =n-1}^\infty a_\tilde \jmath x^\tilde \jmath,  $$
where
$$ a_\tilde \jmath = \begin{cases} 0 & \tilde \jmath<n-1 , \text{ or } \tilde \jmath+1-n \neq 0 \mod {2n} \\ n(-1)^{\frac{\tilde \jmath+1-n}{2n}} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
By uniqueness of Taylor series, we know that
$$ f'(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(j+1)}(0)}{j!}x^j = \sum_{\tilde \jmath =n-1}^\infty a_\tilde \jmath x^\tilde \jmath $$
so one can read off the values of $f^{(j+1)}(0)$ as coefficients of $x^{j}/j!$ in the above expansion. The answer is 
$$ f^{(k)}(0) = \begin{cases} 0 & k<n , \text{ or }  k-n \ne 0 \mod 2n \\ (k-1)!n(-1)^{\frac{k-n}{2n}} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

---

The previous version of this answer did not coincide with Bernard's answer. This is because I thought you computed the first derivative correctly, but you didn't. Specifically, you applied 'chain rule' in the form
$$ (fg)'(x) = f'(x) g'(x)$$
when the correct chain rule is
$$ (fg)'(x) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$$
so the correct first derivative is $nx^{n-1}/(1+x^{2n})$, and not $nx^{n-1}/(1+x^{2})$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Substitute $y = x^n$ in the Maclaruin series $$y - \frac{1}{3} y^3 + \frac{1}{5} y^5 - \frac{1}{7} y^7 + \cdots$$ for $\arctan y$.

Comment: Thanks! I always forget to use Taylor series.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Use the substitution $x^n=u$:
$$\arctan u=\sum_{i\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1}\,u^{2i+1}=\sum_{i\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1}\,x^{(2i+1)n},$$
and remember the coefficient of $x^k$ is $\;\dfrac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}.$